# Determine the largest open subset of C on which the functions below are analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Determine the largest open subset of C on which the functions below are analytic. Give your reason.

(i) $f(z)= \frac{2z+1} {z(z^{2}+1)}$

(ii) $f(z)= \frac{z^{3}+i} {z^{2}-3z+2}$

So I am brushing up on Complex analysis and I am not quite sure if I am doing this right. I know that these are rational functions so they will not be analytic only when the denominator is 0. So for (i), the function is analytic except at z=0, z=i, z=-i. For (ii), the function is analytic except at z=1 and z=2. I am not sure if this is what is being asked for or if it is enough.

Answer (score 0):

f(z)=2zz(z2+1)     this is a rational function so it will not be analytic only where the denominator is 0 i.e.  :
z(z2+1)=0  .

z = 0,    z^2 + 1 = 0,    z = 0,   z^2 = -1,   z = +/- i .

The function is thus analytic except at
z=0,z=−i,z=i

f(z)=z3+iz2−3z+2    .  This will be analytic everywhere except where the denominator is 0, i.e.

z2−3z+2=0
(z−1)(z−2)=0

So this is analytic for all complex numbers except at :
z=1,z=2